# Android app getting Push Notification via FCM but not display the message

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I implemented Push Notification via FCM.
When the app gets a new notification from my server,
The Notification Panel strip noticed by the icon which I set in  NotificationCompat.Builder, But the message not preview as a pop up.
I tried to set priority, style, category, but still the notification not shown.
When I'm scrolling I can see the notification.

I tried the app on 2 different devices OS (6.0.1 & 5.0.1)
Also My backend C# solution - both approches not popup the notification - message and notification

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.theApp"
android:versionCode="31"
android:versionName="0.3.4"  >
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="23" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
   <uses-permission    android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >


    <activity
        android:name="com.theApp.SplashScreen"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>



    <activity
        android:name="com.theApp.MainView"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
     android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar" >
    </activity>


    <service android:name=".FirebaseMessagingService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <service android:name=".FirebaseInstanceIDService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>


</application>




</manifest>
```

FirebaseMessagingService

```
package com.theApp;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import com.google.firebase.messaging.RemoteMessage;
public class FirebaseMessagingService extends    com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService {

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    showNotification(remoteMessage.getData().get("message"));
}
public void showNotification(String message)
{
    Intent i =new Intent(this,MainView.class);
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP ); //FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,i,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setContentTitle("Title")
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
            .bigText(message))
            .setContentText(message)
            .setTicker(message)
            .setVibrate(new long[] { 100, 250, 100, 250, 100, 250 })
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_PROMO);

        NotificationManager manager =   (NotificationManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.NOTI      FICATION_SERVICE);
        manager.notify(0,builder.build());

   }
}
```

Backend (C#):

```
// Data message
  var contentData = new
            {
                registration_ids = tokens,
                priority = "high",
                data = new
                {                       
                    title = "this is title",
                    body = "this is body"
                }
            };

            // Notification message
            var contentData = new
            {
                registration_ids = tokens,
                priority = "high",
                notification = new
                {
                    title = title,
                    body = message
                }
            };
```

Comment: How are you sending the messages to your Android device? Are you using the Firebase console or the REST API?

Comment: @ArthurThompson I'm sending by rest api

Comment: @ArthurThompson even on firebase console - same result

Comment: When using the REST API could you add the request that you are making to the question?

Comment: @ArthurThompson I added my backend code, same result for message and notification!

Comment: did you find solution for this

Comment: I happen to be running into this right now; what was your conclusion?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to read a notification you must call `remoteMessage.getNotification()` rather than calling `remoteMessage.getData()`.Note that `'notification'` key should be available in your server sent payload in order to parse it as a Notification. `getData()` will return a Map only If your server sends a data content. For more information see the [FCM guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/server)

Comment: I tried showNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody()); without  success, same result, push arrives, not popup a preview

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an older question, but to answer it, you need to change the JSON payload in order for it to be handled differently on the device.

See [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40311279/firebase-onmessagereceived-not-called-when-app-is-in-the-background) with regards to why it makes a difference as to the payload being sent.

The short answer is that if you send this as your push notification body to an Android device:

```
{
  "data":{
    "title": "hello",
    "body": "this is body"
  },
  "to": "firebase_long_token_goes_here"
}
```

You will be able to parse it in the onMessageReceived() method and decide whether to or **not** to show it depending on how you parse the JSON. If you send it the *traditional* way or the way IOS can parse it:

```
{
  "notification":{
    "title": "hello",
    "body": "this is body"
  },
  "to": "c5iuJ7iDnoc:APA91bG6j2c5tiQ3rVR9tBdrCTfDQYxkPwLuNFWzRuGHrBpWiOajR-DKef9EZEEVKA-kUBfXVcqHT-mClYfad06R_rBjhRZFKVdBL7_joXE5hFEwR45Qk8wgQdia2b-LmjI1IheFGZS8"
}
```

And the app is in the background, you will have no choice and the system will show it regardless of your desire to hide or not display it.