# In firebase push notifications, when my app is closed, how does firebase push notifications activate back my app?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am reading [this tutorial](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options) about firebase cloud messagging (Push Notifications) and I fail to find any info with regards to the most basic concept in Fire base push notifications.

When my app is closed, how does firebase activate back my app? And which service actually activates it?

Answer (score 1):

Google Play Services must be installed and for these "background data" need to be permitted. This means, an app doesn't receive the notification directly, but it is being pushed into a notification channel, with an optional launch `Intent` ...of the app that is supposed to be launched on tap.

Comment: So these notification are sent by Google Play Service and not by the App?

Answer (score 0):

For Firebase Cloud Messaging (Push Notification):

- When will the push notification be shown:

  - Foreground: no
  - Background: yes
  - Not Alive:  yes
- When will "onMessageReceived()" be called:

  - Foreground: yes
  - Background: if has data
  - Not Alive:  if has data 【and user click on the notification】

Comment: I know about onMessageRceived(). But what is called when "push notification" back ground arrives?

Comment: The `onMessageRceived()` may be called, may not be called, you can check out this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40311279/firebase-onmessagereceived-not-called-when-app-is-in-the-background